# Save Terminal Bazel Build Output

Tags: tensorflow, terminal, bazel

Is it possible to save the output of a bazel build command that is run in terminal?  The command is:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:label_image && 
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/label_image 
--graph=/tmp/output_graph.pb 
--labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt 
--output_layer=final_result:0 
--image=$HOME/Desktop/Image-3/image1.png
```

I want to save the output to a .txt file; I cannot simply tag on > out.txt to the end of the line or I am thrown an error.  But is there bazel-output command?

Comment: Tip: you can use `bazel run :binary -- --arg1=foo, --arg2=bar`

Answer (score 5):

The stdout of the latest `bazel` command is logged in your WORKSPACE's output base:

```
$ echo $(bazel info output_base)
/home/username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_username/3e8af127f8b488324cdf41111355ff4c
```

and the exact file is `command_log`:

```
$ echo $(bazel info command_log)
/home/username/.cache/bazel/_bazel_username/3e8af127f8b488324cdf41111355ff4c/command.log
```

Comment: The command_log truncates to the last INFO line. Everything after that is lost.

Comment: @jin are you sure? Just tried it and found only the name of the same file in it

Comment: @Ittai yes. `bazel info command_log` itself is a bazel command, so you cannot use `echo $(bazel info command_log)` to print the contents of the *last* bazel invocation. You have to use the exact path.

Comment: This file is also accessible via something like this, assuming you're in your git repo's root dir: `build/bin/../../../../../command.log`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by piping the output to both text file and command line, but only on linux. You just append this at the end  `2>&1 | tee file_name.log`